# Internal server error 500 wordpress on server alias

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, alias

I have installed a wordpress site for a client.

The site works fine on local system as well as the test server but not on the live server. The domain is created as an Alias of an existing site. Homepage displays fine but internal pages show blank with a 500 internal server error in Firebug console.

For the past 3 days I've searched and applied all sorts of fixes to .htaccess, code etc but it doesn't seem to fix.

What I've tried:

1. Uploaded the code and database twice.
2. Generated .htaccess fresh using permalinks settings of wordpress.(there are no custom rules in my .htaccess)
3. Set php code to display all errors but there are none, only notices.
4. Talked with the server hosting guy and got the memory limit increased.

What I've not tried yet:

1. Persue the client to create a subdomain instead of an alias.

Please suggest any possible fixes. Thanks!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

UPDATE: Issue Resolved: It was a memory issue on the server. Disabling a few resource-heavy plugins pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Try setting debug to true in your wp-config.php file. This might provide you some more info.

Comment: Also I've checked apache logs which tell this error:Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects... which is apparently an .htaccess related issue

Comment: Well then enable rewrite logging to see what is going on …

Comment: Please update your question by adding the **.htaccess**

Comment: @kanenas.net added the .htaccess

Comment: Does the website works when you switch permalinks to "Default"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /put-the-alias-here/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /put-the-alias-here/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: the alias is not a subdirectory. Its a different domain mapped to this domain as an alias.

Comment: So... in Settings->WordPress Address (URL) and Settings->Site Address (URL) which domain are you using? The Alias or the Domain?

Comment: alias, domain doesn't work. The site's url is the alias only.